# Quasar-cli-vite devServer proxy not working

Tags: vite, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm starting to test Quasar framework and I want to proxy some url to my local backend but the configuration doesn't seem to work ([documentation here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/api-proxying)).
The part of my quasar.config.js where the proxy should be configured:

```
devServer: {
  // https: true
  proxy: {
    '/association': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080',
      changeOrigin: true,
    }
  },
  open: false,
},
```

I've also tried to do it inline `'/association': 'http://localhost:8080'` with the same result. My request are not redirect and query on port 80:  http://localhost/association/setProducerStats
Anyone already managed to configure the proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Quasar is already running itself on port 8080 - try to use a different port for your local backend, or add `port: 8090` to the `devServer` config.

Example config for Vite:

```js
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin';
import viteStylelint from './plugins/stylelint';
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { QuasarResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),

    quasar({
      autoImportComponentCase: 'pascal',
      sassVariables: 'src/quasar-variables.sass'
    }),

    viteStylelint({
      exclude: /node_modules|.*uno\.css/
    }),
    eslintPlugin({
      cache: false
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [QuasarResolver()],
      include: [/\.vue$/],
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.git/, /\.nuxt/],
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    https: false,
    port: 9000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://api.example.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: true,
        //rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    terserOptions: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
      },
    },
    // reportCompressedSize: true,
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1024,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id)
        {
          if (id.includes('/node_modules/'))
          {
            const modules = ['quasar', '@quasar', 'vue', '@vue'];
            const chunk = modules.find((module) => id.includes(`/node_modules/${module}`));
            return chunk ? `vendor-${chunk}` : 'vendor';
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: my Quasar frontend is running on port 9000 by default.

Comment: Hm, then it does not make sense - because if I use your config on my PC and set the target to my remote backend server, it works just fine.

Comment: Weird.. It works just fine if I use Vite directly

Comment: What do you mean by `directly` ?! `vite.config.js` uses `server` instead of `devServer`.

Comment: Yes using a vite.config.js  with `server` and running Vite. I said "directly" because Quasar passes `devServer` to Vite `server` -> https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/12979#discussioncomment-2496405

Comment: Well, then you have an option to use Vite directly instead of using Quasar to pass some config to Vite. Take a look at the example config in my answer.